# Adding .jpg images to a specific template in LaTeX

Tags: graphics

I found this template online for a scientific style journal but I am unfamiliar with the packages and am having a lot of trouble adding .jpg images as figures.

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{"Picture I want to add"}
\end{figure}
```

is giving me nothing.

This is the template that I am working with: https://www.writelatex.com/381932qnwwkv

Answer (score 1):

For JPEG pictures people typically use the `graphicx` package:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

If you are getting any error messages, it might also help to post those.